# Save button redirect to home Joomla 3.5.1

Tags: php, joomla

Recently i installed Joomla in a hosting service, however when i add a template or modify global configuration, when i try to save or cancel, the administrator redirects to index page of site Exiting from administration and not save changes.

When i tun the project on localhost works without issues.

I had modified permissions for file configuration.php and i change the templates and search directly on code without a solution.

i search in forums and documentation and i do not find response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change your configuration of host server in `projectfolder/configuration.php` file

Comment: hi, i change the host configuration and still do not working, i have a clean installation of joomla, i already verify permissions and appears work fine. But i have no idea of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solvet it. It appears have a problem with mod_security, i disable it and the joomla cofiguration Working.